How To Make An Input That Checks A Specific String In An Array (Python)
Is there a way so that I can make the user input "1" and it would check a variable to see if the value matches 1. For example, could I have the user input 1 and it would convert the input to a different string depending on what the number was.
import random
from colorama import *
startcolor = [Fore.RED, Fore.GREEN, Fore.BLUE, Fore.YELLOW, Fore.MAGENTA, Fore.CYAN, Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX]
print(random.choice(startcolor) + "Type the number, not the color!\n\n" + Fore.RESET)
print(Fore.RED + "1 = Red\n" + 
  Fore.BLUE + "2 - Blue\n" + 
  Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "3 - Light Blue\n" + 
  Fore.GREEN + "4 = Green\n" + 
  Fore.CYAN + "5 = Cyan\n" + 
  Fore.YELLOW + "6 = Yellow\n" + 
  Fore.MAGENTA + "7 = Magenta\n")
words = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Magenta", "Cyan"]
color = random.choice(startcolor)
print(color + random.choice(words) + Fore.RESET)

How can I make the user input a number to check if the number matches the word?

Are you trying to get the item at a specific index in a list by using a number?

Use a dictionary like outputs = {'1': 'Red', '2': 'Blue', ...}. Then you can do something like print(outputs[user_input]).

I would recommend using a dictionary to provide a mapping for the colors.
For example,
availabe_colors = {
    "Red": Fore.RED,
    "Green": Fore.GREEN,
    "Blue": Fore.BLUE,
    # Add more here
}

Because the type of startcolor is change from list to dict, you also need to modify the way which you randomly choose a color.
# Instead of
random.choice(startcolor)

# Do this instead
random.choice(list(availabe_colors.values()))

Then, when printing the different colors, you can use a loop to print it. This way, you don't have add new code when you need to support more colors.
for idx, color in enumerate(availabe_colors):
    print(availabe_colors[color] + "{} = {}".format(idx + 1, color))

If your version of python doesn't support enumerate(), you can do this instead,
for colur_idx in range(0, len(availabe_colors)):
    print(list(availabe_colors.values())[colur_idx] + "{} = {}".format(colur_idx + 1, list(availabe_colors.keys())[colur_idx]))

Putting it together, your original code would look something like this,
import random
from colorama import *

availabe_colors = {
    "Red": Fore.RED,
    "Green": Fore.GREEN,
    "Blue": Fore.BLUE,
    # Add more here
}

print(random.choice(list(availabe_colors.values())) + "Type the number, not the color!\n\n" + Fore.RESET)
for idx, color in enumerate(availabe_colors):
    print(availabe_colors[color] + "{} = {}".format(idx + 1, color))

words = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Magenta", "Cyan"]
color = random.choice(list(availabe_colors.values()))
print(color + random.choice(words) + Fore.RESET)


I wasn't too sure what you where trying to do with the last part, so I just copied and pasted the code without modification.
If you want words to be the colors which are supported, you can do
words = list(availabe_colors.keys())
print(words) # ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']

